# Create an filter switch on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an Excel document with a table named "Employees".

I want to create buttons that will toggle some filter (on/off).

Example:

```
Default table:
Id | Name  | Last name | Status
---+-------+-----------+---------
 1 | Alice | Alpha     | Active
 2 | Bob   | Beta      | Active
 3 | Alice | Charlie   | Inactive
 4 | Carol | Delta     | Active
 5 | Lewis | Echo      | Inactive

[Toggle active/all]:
Id | Name  | Last name | Status
---+-------+-----------+---------
 1 | Alice | Alpha     | Active
 2 | Bob   | Beta      | Active
 4 | Carol | Delta     | Active

[Toggle Alice/all]:
Id | Name  | Last name | Status
---+-------+-----------+---------
 1 | Alice | Alpha     | Active
 3 | Alice | Charlie   | Inactive
```

These 2 buttons would only create a filter on the adequate column, or remove it if it is already created. This way, I can use both buttons to filter on active Alice employees.

```
[Toggle active/all] + [Toggle Alice/all]:
Id | Name  | Last name | Status
---+-------+-----------+---------
 1 | Alice | Alpha     | Active
```

As of now, I can create a filter that way:

```
' Create a filter on 'Alice'
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employees").ListObjects("Employees").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Alice"
' Create a filter on 'active'
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employees").ListObjects("Employees").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Active"
```

But I don't know how to check if on of this filter is activated.

Answer (score -1):

*You need to create a Toggle Button on the Sheet*.

Let me say how.

*Create a Command button, name it for example Fltrbutton, modify it's Caption as Alice. Then in VB editor create this code.*

```
Sub Fltrbutton_click()

ActiveSheet.AutofilterMode = False

If Fltrbutton.Caption = "Alice" then

      ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$D$20").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Alice"

    Fltrbutton.Caption = "Active"

Endif

If Fltrbutton.Caption = "Active" then

     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$30:$D$50").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Active"

   Fltrbutton.Caption = "Alice"

Endif

End Sub
```

I do hope this sample code will help you to exercise the Code properly for both the Criteria.

**NB:** Change the Data Range and others as you need.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, `Alice` and `Active` are 2 separate buttons, which allow to apply the 2 filters independantly. `ActiveSheet.AutofilterMode` applies to a whole sheet, not to a selected Table. Unfortunately, this answer doesn't provide more than the filters I already created.

Comment: It's really great,, read this was your QUERY,, "I want to create buttons that will toggle some filter (on/off)." And I've suggested you the VBA Code which is Toggling the Filter, mind you ! And NO NEED to add ActiveWorkbook, since it's followed by Sheet & Table Name(Employee),,!! And I've used the ActiveSheet  with Data Range will do the same what your Code did !! BETTER YOU TRY the Code before you be judgemental !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no need to get emotional over this. :)
Unfortunately, your code doesn't work with the provided examples. As I stated in my previous comment, `Alice` and `Active` are two separate buttons that can be *switched* on and off.

Comment: @JDOE,, Let me remind you that Toggle Button means, 'single button which can perform more than one job,,,'. I never mind if my answer DOWN VOTED but there must be a genuine reason. What you are trying is 2 buttons doing 2 Jobs,, but in my example the single button is doing both the jobs and that's what the TOGGLE BUTTON :-).